# IRQL_GT_ZERO_AT_SYSTEM_SERVICE since Windows update

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-update

I'm getting this STOP error after I updated Windows 7 using Windows Update. I made a system restore in order to try to solve temporarily. I don't want to stay outdated and exposed, so I searched and found this page about the error, **[IRQL GT ZERO AT SYSTEM SERVICE 0x0000004a](http://www.faultwire.com/solutions-fatal_error/IRQL-GT-ZERO-AT-SYSTEM-SERVICE-0x0000004A-*1089.html)**.

The problem is that it does not help me understand what the real problem is. For now I want to install all updates since 5 January 2013 except the problematic one, but the combinations are `20!`(factorial) which is an insane amount.

Do you know which recent Windows 7 Update may have caused this?

Specs

- OS: Windows 6.1 build 6001 (SP1) Home edition
- Technical details of the STOP error

  ```
  Bugcheck: 0x0000004a (0x00000000746e2e09, 0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000, 0xfffff8800c3a2c60)  
  Report ID: 011713-66674-01
  ```

Comment: This indicates that a thread is returning to user mode from a system call when its IRQL is still above PASSIVE_LEVEL

Comment: @Snesticle That's what I thought. But what's the cause of it? If it a faulty windows update? Was it an update that wasn't properly applied? ...?

Comment: Just install one update at a time.  Since every single update creates a system restore point before its installed the process should only take an hour at most.

Comment: Do what Ramhound just said. The hex code in parentheses next to the 0x0000004a should supply the current IRQL but I'm a GNU guy so I'm not much help there.

Comment: If I had to take a guess I would say that an update conflicted with one of your hardware drivers but that's pure speculation.

Comment: Dunno why, I lost almost all restores from system restore after updating 2 updates from windows update. Then I got the STOP error... Now I only have one restore point... How come I lost all those restore points?